# OWA on exchange 2003 does not work

Tags: exchange, outlook-web-app

I have a problem setting owa up on a testmilieu for exchange 2003! Actually I didn't install exchange 2003, I just got the case about getting owa to function and at the same time I don't know that much about exchange 2003.

When I hit this in the browser (on exchange server): http://localhost/exchange, I should get a loginform, right? I just keep getting 404 - page not found!

I get the loginform when I hit: http://localhost/exchweb/bin/auth/owalogon.asp?url=https://localhost/exchange&reason=0, but this redirects me to http://localhost/exchweb/bin/auth/owaauth.dll ???

This smells like a bad installation, or is it just some wsettings I have missed?

Any help is appriciated...

/Finn.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually the problem wasn't that technical and I'm a bit embarrased to admit that I discovered that asp.net was set to .net 4.0! I changed that to .net 2.0 and resat the virtual directories and voila!

Cheers for the help...

/Finn

Answer (score 0):

Actually my Exchange 2003 reports itself as `https://external.domain.com/exchweb/bin/auth/owalogon.asp?url=https://external.domain.com/exchange&reason=0` after i type in https://external.domain.com so your localhost query looks ok to me. What kind of problem are you having? That when you type `http://localhost/exchange` it doesn't work but when you type `http://localhost/exchweb/bin/auth/owalogon.asp?url=https://localhost/exchange&reason=0` it does work ?  Also have you tried using https://localhost/exchange?

Take a look at your IIS it's where it's set up. You should be checking the ports, ip iis is working on and http/https settings.

If you're IIS is in bad shape and you want to reinstall it (as per your comment) take a look at this articles:

- http://blog.crowe.co.nz/archive/2006/05/30/643.aspx
- http://support.microsoft.com/default.aspx?scid=kb;en-us;320202

As per quote from the first article it's not really a walk in the park:

> Apparently when you remove IIS you have also removed some additional configuration parameters that exchange has added to the IIS Metabase and you must follow the 6 steps below to relink the attributes when you install IIS again.

```
1. Back Up Data
2. Dismount the Mailbox and the Public Information Store
3. Stop Exchange Services and Remove IIS
4. Reinstall Internet Information Service and Reapply Service Packs
5. Reinstall Exchange Server
6. Restore the Original Exchange Information Store
```

So think hard before reinstalling IIS. I guess it's "simpler" to try to fix it.

Comment: My problem is that http://localhost/exchange and https://localhost/exchange does not work (of course with ssl turned on for the https), I only get "Internet Explorer cannot display the webpage" for both of them.

Comment: How does it look in IIS?

Comment: I'm a little bit confused, my iis 6 does not look healthy the way I remembered it to be. And it does not look like the system recognizes it! I'll try reinstall and get back to you, might be over the weekend! Thanks for now, MadBoy. I'll keep you updated!

Comment: Thanks a lot, MadBoy! I'll check it out. I think I will setup a virtual box in the weekend, and install everything from the bottom, just to learn about it. And then see how I can get around it in my testmilieu! Cheers...

Comment: Hmm- Sorry for the delay in answering! I didn't make a clean install on virtual box, because it's too timeconsuming - you have to setup a dc and everything just to install exchange 2003. Instead I have tried to investigate a little bit, as madboy sugested. I have done a reset on the virtual directories in IIS, by editing the metabase.xml settings. But this didn't do anything. The reason why I think my IIS is not healthy is that I recon that one used to see the IIS ver.no. when hitting help/about IIS...but it doesn't. I'll get back with some more update...

Comment: I can try to resolve your problems remotely so if you wish contact me per details on my profile (on email) and we should figure something out. Without a lot more details it's hard to help.

Comment: Yes, I know, madboy. I appriciate your effort to help! It's a little tricky, though. The server is a "production-test" server which is behind our firewall. Let me give it a shot more and I'll get back in the morning...Cheers Finn.

Comment: Status: Configured directories Exchweb and Exchange in IIS to use ssl (properties->Directory Security->Secure communications/Edit->check: require secure channel and ignore client certificates). Then when browsing both https://localhost/exchange and https://localhost//exchweb/bin/auth/owalogon.asp via https, I get "Internet Explorer cannot display the webpage...! (ExchangeApplicationPool and doesn't matter what Execute permissions are)...

Comment: What settings do you have in IIS under World Wide Web - Default Web when you right click it and choose properties does it have ip addresses set correctly, port ssl to 4433 and Advanced set as well?

Comment: When not setting ssl and browsing http://localhost/exchweb/bin/auth/owalogon.asp, I get the owa logon form! When I click logon I get /localhost/exchange/ and "The page cannot be found"

Comment: Ip addr=All unassigned, tcp port=80 and ssl port=443!

Comment: I don't think I can help you more without seeing things. LogMeIn Free is your choice to get things past firewall. You install it on your desktop and let people login to your computer (you can see mouse/keyboard working). Then you connect to server thru RDP and you can let someone work on it. That's how I help my customers.

Comment: I appriciate your effort, MadBoy. But my technical director tells me, and I agree with him, that only employees and customers are allowed remote control. I will set time off to spawn a new virtual box and do it all from bottom and up, and I will be posting here alongside as the server gets up. Cheers...

Comment: I understand. That's up to you.